# Send log from PhantomJS to Graylog2

Tags: phantomjs, graylog2, graylog

I'm trying to send a log message from PhantomJS script to Graylog. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: How does PhantomJS emit logs? On standard out? Into log files on disk? How are they formatted?

Comment: Now I have just a Console.log messages.

Comment: In this case, take a look at the Graylog Collector Sidecar: http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.1/pages/collector_sidecar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
function remoteLog(message) {

var page = require('webpage').create(),
server = 'http://10.68.130.24:12202/gelf',
data = '{"short_message":"' + message + '", "host":"phantomjs.smediresource.com", "project" : "Dynacare", "facility":"phantomJS", "environment":"QA", "application": "phantomJS", "content": "applicationLog"}';

page.open(server, 'post', data, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.error('Unable to post!');
    } 
    page.close();
});

}
```

It works but generate some crashes due to a memory leak of PhantomJS.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this plugin to collect log produce by phantomjs.

https://marketplace.graylog.org/addons/26035144-0c04-4ca5-8848-6ed1323a84a4

Comment: Wrong link? This is an (outdated) input for the Lumberjack (now Beats) protocol in Graylog.